# How can I format my grep output to show line numbers at the end of the line, and also the hit count?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep

I'm using grep to match string in a file. Here is an example file:

```
example one,
example two null,
example three,
example four null,
```

`grep -i null myfile.txt` returns

```
example two null,
example four null,
```

How can I return matched lines together with their line numbers like this:

```
  example two null, - Line number : 2
  example four null, - Line number : 4
  Total null count : 2
```

I know -c returns total matched lines, but I don't how to format it properly to add `total null count` in front, and I don't know how to add the line numbers.

What can I do?

Answer (score 687, accepted):

`-n` returns line number.

`-i` is for ignore-case. Only to be used if case matching is not necessary

```
$ grep -in null myfile.txt

2:example two null,
4:example four null,
```

Combine with `awk` to print out the line number after the match:

```
$ grep -in null myfile.txt | awk -F: '{print $2" - Line number : "$1}'

example two null, - Line number : 2
example four null, - Line number : 4
```

Use command substitution to print out the total null count:

```
$ echo "Total null count :" $(grep -ic null myfile.txt)

Total null count : 2
```

Comment: can I format this by adding line numbers after instead of before with :?

Comment: your solution seems fine but get an error `awk95: syntax error at source line
 context is
         >>> ' <<<
        missing }
awk95: bailing out at source line 1`

Comment: sorry switched to linux now its working :) it was windows version not so good

Comment: ...the knights who say `-ni` thats how you remember this trick

Answer (score 66):

Use `-n` or `--line-number`.

Check out `man grep` for lots more options.

Comment: new linux user is lazy of reading man page. But if they use linux enough, they will be used to it :) It's super useful :)

Comment: Not always lazy, (But sometimes), often it is that a new Linux user has trouble understanding a man page. (They can _seem_ cryptic)

Comment: sometimes man page can take many pages. And this is hard to read all of them

Answer (score 8):

use `grep -n -i null myfile.txt` to output the line number in front of each match.

I dont think grep has a switch to print the count of total lines matched, but you can just pipe grep's output into wc to accomplish that:

```
grep -n -i null myfile.txt | wc -l
```

Comment: -c will print the total lines matched

Comment: You are right. Unfortunately it also suppresses normal output.

Answer (score 7):

Or use `awk` instead:

```
awk '/null/ { counter++; printf("%s%s%i\n",$0, " - Line number: ", NR)} END {print "Total null count: " counter}' file
```

Answer (score 4):

`grep` find the lines and output the line numbers, but does not let you "program" other things. If you want to include arbitrary text and do other "programming", you can use awk,

```
$ awk '/null/{c++;print $0," - Line number: "NR}END{print "Total null count: "c}' file
example two null,  - Line number: 2
example four null,  - Line number: 4
Total null count: 2
```

Or only using the shell(bash/ksh)

```
c=0
while read -r line
do
  case "$line" in
   *null* )  (
    ((c++))
    echo "$line - Line number $c"
    ;;
  esac
done < "file"
echo "total count: $c"
```

Answer (score 3):

or in perl (for completeness...):

```
perl -npe 'chomp; /null/ and print "$_ - Line number : $.\n" and $i++;$_="";END{print "Total null count : $i\n"}'
```

Answer (score 3):

Refer this link for linux command linux
http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/grep1.html

for displaying line no ,line of code and file use this command in your terminal or cmd, GitBash(Powered by terminal)

```
grep -irn "YourStringToBeSearch"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just thought I'd something that might help you in the future. To search multiple string and output line numbers and browse thru the output, type:

`egrep -ne 'null|three'`

will show:

```
2:example two null,  
3:example three,  
4:example four null,
```

`egrep -ne 'null|three' | less`

will display output in a less session

HTH
Jun