# Reliably checking wget log for errors using grep or ack

Tags: bash, awk, grep, wget, ack

In a bash file, I have `logfileA.txt` that contains output from `wget` that I'd like to run `grep` on to check for any instances of the words "error" or "fail", etc, as so:

```
grep -ni --color=never -e "error" -e "fail" logfileA.txt | awk -F: '{print "Line "$1": "$2}'
# grep -n line number, -i ignore case; awk to add better format to the line numbers (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968103)
```

Trouble is though, I think the `wget` output in `logfileA.txt` is full of characters that may be messing up the input for `grep`, as I'm not getting reliable matches.

Troubleshooting this, I cannot even `cat` the contents of the log file reliably. For instance, with `cat logfileA.txt`, all I get is the last line which is garbled:

```
FINISHED --2019-05-29 17:08:52--me@here:/home/n$ 71913592/3871913592]atmed out). Retrying.
```

The contents of `logfileA.txt` is:

```
--2019-05-29 15:26:50--  http://somesite.com/somepath/a0_FooBar/BarFile.dat
Reusing existing connection to somesite.com:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://cdn.somesite.com/storage/a0_FooBar/BarFile.dat [following]
--2019-05-29 15:26:50--  http://cdn.somesite.com/storage/a0_FooBar/BarFile.dat
Resolving cdn.somesite.com (cdn.somesite.com)... xxx.xxx.xx.xx
Connecting to cdn.somesite.com (cdn.somesite.com)|xxx.xxx.xx.xx|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3871913592 (3.6G) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: 'a0_FooBar/BarFile.dat’

a0_FooBar/BarFile.dat   0%[                    ]       0  --.-KB/s               
a0_FooBar/BarFile.dat   0%[                    ]  15.47K  70.5KB/s               
...
a0_FooBar/BarFile.dat  49%[========>           ]   1.80G  --.-KB/s    in 50m 32s 

2019-05-29 16:17:23 (622 KB/s) - Read error at byte 1931163840/3871913592 (Connection timed out). Retrying.

--2019-05-29 16:17:24--  (try: 2)  http://cdn.somesite.com/storage/a0_FooBar/BarFile.dat
Connecting to cdn.somesite.com (cdn.somesite.com)|xxx.xxx.xx.xx|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 206 Partial Content
Length: 3871913592 (3.6G), 1940749752 (1.8G) remaining [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: 'a0_FooBar/BarFile.dat’

a0_FooBar/BarFile.dat  49%[+++++++++           ]   1.80G  --.-KB/s               
...
a0_FooBar/BarFile.dat 100%[+++++++++==========>]   3.61G  1.09MB/s    in 34m 44s 

2019-05-29 16:52:09 (909 KB/s) - 'a0_FooBar/BarFile.dat’ saved [3871913592/3871913592]

FINISHED --2019-05-29 17:08:52--
```

I assume the problem could be the `/`s or `---`s or `>`s or `==>`s or `|`s?

But since the output from `wget` could vary, how do I anticipate and escape anything problematical for `grep`?

#### Command:

```
grep -ni --color=never -e "error" -e "fail" logfileA.txt | awk -F: '{print "Line "$1": "$2}'
```

#### Expected output:

```
Line 17: 2019-05-29 16:17:23 (622 KB/s) - Read error at byte 1931163840/3871913592 (Connection timed out). Retrying.
```

Also, would an `ack` line be better at this job? And if so, what/how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrt `I assume the problem could be the /s or ---s or >s or ==>s or |s?` - no, there's nothing special about any of those characters/strings. It sounds like you might have DOS line endings (`\r\n`), see [Why does my tool output overwrite itself and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it?noredirect=1#comment97778025_45772525). Since you said `with cat logfileA.txt, all I get is the last line which is garbled` I wonder if you ONLY have `\r`s and no `\n`s as line endings. If you do then `tr '\r' '\n' < logfileA.txt > tmp && mv tmp logfileA.txt` would fix that. If that IS the issue then going forward you can use `awk -v RS='\r' 'script'` to change the record separator from it's default `\n` to `\r` and then you won't need to do that `tr` step.

You don't need grep when you're using awk though. This:

```
grep -ni --color=never -e "error" -e "fail" logfileA.txt |
    awk -F: '{print "Line "$1": "$2}'
```

can be written as just:

```
awk 'tolower($0) ~ /error|fail/{print "Line "NR":"$0}' logfileA.txt
```

but the awk-only version is more robust as it'll correctly display full lines that contain `:`s where the grep+awk version will truncate them to the first `:`.

You can handle the DOS line endings, if any, by tweaking the script to:

```
awk 'tolower($0) ~ /error|fail/{sub(/\r$/,""); print "Line "NR":"$0}' logfileA.txt
```

and you can make it look for error or fail as standalone words (as opposed to part of other strings like `terror` or `failles`) by doing this with GNU awk:

```
awk -v IGNORECASE=1 -v RS='\r?\n' '/\<(error|fail)\>/{print "Line "NR":"$0}' logfileA.txt
```

or this with any awk:

```
awk 'tolower($0) ~ /(^|[^[:alnum:]_])(error|fail)([^[:alnum:]_]|$)/{sub(/\r$/,""); print "Line "NR":"$0}' logfileA.txt
```

Comment: How can `awk -v IGNORECASE=1 -v RS='\r?\n' '/\<(error|fail)\>/{print "Line "NR":"$0}' logfileA.txt` be modified to catch "errors" and "failed" but not "terror" and "failles"?

Comment: Just change the regexp to `/\<(errors?|fail(ed)?)\>/`